# Tap action has na effect on emulator but giving timeout issue- Detox

Tags: detox

In my test, when I click on a button to navigate to the next page, But the test timeouts saying it did not receive any response to the tap action.

Environment:

- "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
- "babel-jest": " 24.9.0,"
- "detox": "^17.14.9",
- React Native:"0.62.2",
- Node: v12.21.0.
- Device: Pixel_2_API_28 emulator
- OS: Android

I have tested this issue on the latest Detox release and it still reproduces.